# Drupal commerce price markup field

Tags: commerce

I need to calculate product sell price as gross price * markup (i.e. 1.4) Gross price is stored in field_data_commerce_price table (standard commerce price field). Markup value should be associated with every single product, so I can manage it with views using filters and VBO. I have many product types, so maually created markup field is not a good solution.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution?

and if not:

What is the best way to add new product field using API? (should be added by default for all product types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a per product price modificator, your best solution is to have a field with this information, you can probably use a normal numeric field for this purpose.

You've got many examples on how to create a field using the API, for example, drupal commerce itself adds a price field every time a product type is generated by using [hook_modules_enabled](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7) hook.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_modules_enabled().
 */
function commerce_product_modules_enabled($modules) {
  commerce_product_configure_product_fields($modules);
}
```

Then in this function

```
function commerce_product_configure_product_fields($modules = NULL) {
(...)
      // Loop through and configure the product types defined by the module.
      foreach ($product_types as $type => $product_type) {
        commerce_product_configure_product_type($type);
      }
```

Next

```
/**
 * Ensures a base price field is present on a product type bundle.
 */
function commerce_product_configure_product_type($type) {
  commerce_price_create_instance('commerce_price', 'commerce_product', $type, t('Price'), 0, 'calculated_sell_price');
}
```

And finally

```
function commerce_price_create_instance($field_name, $entity_type, $bundle, $label, $weight = 0, $calculation = FALSE, $display = array()) {
  // Look for or add the specified price field to the requested entity bundle.
  commerce_activate_field($field_name);
  field_cache_clear();

  $field = field_info_field($field_name);
  $instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

  if (empty($field)) {
    $field = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'type' => 'commerce_price',
      'cardinality' => 1,
      'entity_types' => array($entity_type),
      'translatable' => FALSE,
      'locked' => TRUE,
    );
    $field = field_create_field($field);
  }

  if (empty($instance)) {
    $instance = array(
      'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => $entity_type,
      'bundle' => $bundle,

      'label' => $label,
      'required' => TRUE,
      'settings' => array(),

      // Because this widget is locked, we need it to use the full price widget
      // since the currency option can't be adjusted at the moment.
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'commerce_price_full',
        'weight' => $weight,
        'settings' => array(
          'currency_code' => 'default',
        ),
      ),

      'display' => array(),
    );

    $entity_info = entity_get_info($entity_type);

    // Spoof the default view mode and node teaser so its display type is set.
    $entity_info['view modes'] += array(
      'default' => array(),
      'node_teaser' => array(),
    );

    foreach ($entity_info['view modes'] as $view_mode => $data) {
      $instance['display'][$view_mode] = $display + array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'commerce_price_formatted_amount',
        'settings' => array(
          'calculation' => $calculation,
        ),
        'weight' => $weight,
      );
    }

    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}
```

So you in summary can use hook_modules_enabled to react and loop the product types and create your field and instance. Another examples of this procedure can be found in [commerce recurring](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_recurring/tree/commerce_recurring.module#n86), commerce discount, commerce coupon and more.

Comment: Thanks, pcambra, I've implemented suggested hook_modules_enabled and "markup" field appeared in all commerce_product bundles, but when I trying to modify entity values with VBO it treats every field instance (one for each bundle) as separate field, so I can't modify markup value for all bundles in one simple action without "crazy checkboxing": (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42690200/VBO-checkboxes.PNG)

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the number of fields/product types you've got. If that's not manageable, you can create your own action for VBO and select the field for each type (saving it in a variable, like commerce does for the customer profile address field), that'd give you a single checkbox.